# Unwanted white border around html image on startup

Tags: html, css, image

I've seen other posts about this but none of their suggestions/answers helped me. There is a white border around my image control that span 100% width of the browser. It only appears on "Image1" below and not "Image2" which I thought was strange. I have also tried setting the border to black, 0px width, etc.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Radar.aspx.cs" Inherits="RadarOnTheInternet.Radar" %>
```

```css
body {
            background-color: black;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #Image1 {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90.0vh;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            top: 5.0vh;
            bottom: 0px;
            object-fit: contain;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        #Image2 {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90.0vh;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            top: 5.0vh;
            bottom: 0px;
            object-fit: contain;
            z-index: 0;
        }                       
        #Panel1 {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            background-color: black;
            border: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: green;
            width: 9%;
            height: 5.0vh;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #Label1 {
            display: flex;
            background-color: black;
            color: green;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 2.0vmin;
            font-family: "Courier New";
        }
        #Label2 {
            display: flex;
            background-color: black;
            color: green;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 2.0vmin;
            font-family: "Courier New";
        }
        #Panel2 {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            background-color: black;
            border-top: solid;
            border-right: solid;
            border-bottom: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: green;
            width: 3.5%;
            height: 5.0vh;
            float: left;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        #Button1 {
            display: flex;
            border: 0;
            outline: none;
            background-color: black;
            color: green;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 2.0vmin;
            font-family: "Courier New";
        }
        #Button2 {
            display: flex;
            border: 0;
            border-top: solid;
            border-top-width: 1px;
            outline: none;
            background-color: black;
            color: green;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 2.0vmin;
            font-family: "Courier New";
        }
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Radar.aspx.cs" Inherits="RadarOnTheInternet.Radar" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>   
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer id="Timer1" OnTick="Timer_tick" Interval="100" runat="server">
                </asp:Timer>
                <asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server">           
                    <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text="RANGE" />
                    <asp:Label id="Label2" runat="server" Text="6 NM" />
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel id="Panel2" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="+" OnClick="Button1_click" />
                    <asp:Button id="Button2" runat="server" Text="-" OnClick="Button2_click" />
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Image id="Image2" runat="server" />
                <asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Unwanted white border]

Comment: You may want to share codesandbox, as it helps us checking the entire code for error, see here -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You've shown us some sort of backend templating. I asked for HTML (on which CSS acts). Also, _create a snippet_. It's right there in the editor toolbar.

Comment: maybe an online editor with an example would help you to show us your issue : https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was able to remove this white border by setting the Image1.ImageUrl to a blank black background on startup like such:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.Clear(Color.Black);

            byte[] blackData;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                blackData = ms.ToArray();
            }
            if (blackData != null)
            {
                //This remove an unwanted white border around the image that shows on startup.
                Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(blackData);
                UpdatePanel1.Update();
            }
```